# Throwing "Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined" in react range slider

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm

I have followed the nodejs react range slider component instructions (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rangeslider). I have installed all dependencies but still i'm getting "value is not defined" error. I don't know why its happening.
Here, i have included my code,

```
var React  = require('react');
var Slider = require('react-rangeslider');

var Volume = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            value: 10,
        };
    },
    handleChange: function(value) {
        this.setState({
            value: value,
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Slider value={value} orientation="vertical" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Volume;
```

Comment: kya @Sathya kuch bhi post kar deta hai bina dekhe hi

Comment: Sorry @DhavalPatel. I don't know hindhi.

Comment: then you can use https://www.google.co.in/search?q=google+translate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=-8aDVq-9EdGOuASFhoDwCA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `value` here is not defined:

```
<Slider value={value} orientation="vertical" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Use the value in your state instead

```
<Slider value={this.state.value} orientation="vertical" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```